# @singleton in gwt usage

Tags: gwt, singleton

I have an object **PanelDataHandler** which is like

```java
 @Singleton
 public class PanelDataHandler {
    private List<Panel> panelDetails;
    private  Integer nextId;
    @Inject
    public PanelDataHandler(){
        panelDetails = new ArrayList<Panel>();
        nextId = 0;

    }     
...
}
```

Now there are two buttons with different handlers in my code. on button is to **save** the details of the panels saved and the other to display the **list** of panels entered.
I have gone through many posts and stackoverflow question couldn't arrive to a solution.
I want to create an Instance of `PanelDataHandler pdh` and add the panels to it in one handler and get the added list of panels in another handler.

```java
public class PanelSaveEventHandler implements EventHandler {

    public void savePanelsList() {
       pdh.addPanels();

    }

}
```

getting the list

```java
public class PanelClickEventHandler implements EventHandler{
    public void displayPanelGrid() {

        MyPagingDataGrid<Panel> grid = new MyPagingDataGrid<Panel>();
        grid.setHeight("500px");
        grid.setDataList(pdh.getPanelList());
        RootPanel.get().add(grid);

    }

}
```

My Ginjector interface

```
@GinModules({ DispatchAsyncModule.class, ClientModule.class })
public interface ClientGinjector extends Ginjector {
...
...

    AsyncProvider<PanelDataHandler> getPanelDataHandler();
}
```

My EntryPoint is

```
public class PanelEstimator implements EntryPoint {

    private final ClientGinjector ginjector = GWT.create(ClientGinjector.class);
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // This is required for Gwt-Platform proxy's generator
        DelayedBindRegistry.bind(ginjector);    
        ginjector.getPlaceManager().revealCurrentPlace();
        System.out.println(ginjector.getPanelDataHandler());
    }

}
```

Where and how can I create instance for `PanelDataHandler` so that it can be used as above

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: Are you using `GWTP`?

Comment: I don't understand the problem..If you use one GinInjector and use the PanelDataHandler as Singleton, you should always get the same instance of your pdh if you @Inject them at the places in your code you need them.

Comment: I couldn't understand the answer, how to @inject where ever I need it. Do u mean when ever I create instance for PanelDataHandler it will be pointing to same pdh. I have added the code of Ginjector and EntryPoint for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution for my problems, thanks for the valuable suggestions
For using singleton object, it has to be injected i.e,

@Inject
PanelDataHandler pdh;

it is not

PanelDataHandler pdh=new PanelDataHandler();